# Редактирование таблицы с помощью microsoft.office.interop.word c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

Здравствуйте!
Создаю документ word из шаблона с рамкой. При создании таблицы она наползает на рамку. Подскажите, как сдвинуть ее вправо?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Короче, разобрался. За отступ от левого края для таблицы отвечает свойство строк:

```
table.Rows.LeftIndent = 70;
```

Еще нашел полезную штуку: в Word'е можно записать макрос и потом посмотреть его код на VBA